# Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, whitespace, pipe

I am trying out some regex patterns here is one I have attempted unsuccessfully: an input string (min:1,max:100) should not have leading and trailing whitespaces or pipe characters and should not have a pipe character within the string. There can be spaces within the string.
So far this what I came up with:

```
"^([^\\s^\\|]*)([^\\|]+)([\\S&&[^\\|]]*)$"
```

But this pattern counts leading and trailing spaces as spaces within the string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post an example of a string that should match and another that should not match?

Comment: The reason it "counts leading and trailing spaces as spaces within the string" is the use of "\*" in your first and last terms.  The easiest match to a "\*" expression is always "" (i.e. nothing), and because your middle term doesn't exclude spaces, the matcher will include them.  I get caught on this, too, still. :(  "\*" is for truly optional, and NOT for "do not want"...

Comment: For the pattern in my original post, here's a string that matches when it shouldn't: " 5"

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question as written:

```
^[^\s|][^|]+[^\s|]$
```

Another possibility to add restriction on length:

```
^([^\s]{1,100}|[^\s|][^|]{1,98}[^\s|])$
```

But did you write your question as desired?  From your later statement, are you trying to strip out leading/trailing spaces or pipe characters?  That would be different:

```
s/^\s+(.*?)\s+/$1/
s/\|//g
```

Comment: Seth, I tried your pattern initially, but it returns false for a single character,like "5","g"....The pattern should accept single characters also. To clarify,I am trying to strip leading and trailing whitespaces & pipe characters, and pipe characters within the string. It should be acceptable to have spaces in the string.

Comment: @Shaun: Did you try my second pattern?  That should allow single characters.